# How to update unique value in c# datagridview - error "cannot insert duplicate key in object"

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datagridview

It should be popular problem but I do not manage to find a solution.
My code is on datagridview cell change event and looks like this:

```
    private void dtgMachines_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if(dgvMachines.CurrentRow != null)
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(strConn))
            {
                DataGridViewRow dtgRow = dgvMachines.CurrentRow;
                SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("pp_sp_Machines_AddEdit", sqlConn);
                sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                if (dtgRow.Cells["txtMachineID"].Value == DBNull.Value)
                {//Insert
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MachineID", 0);
                }
                else
                {//Update
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MachineID", Convert.ToInt32(dtgRow.Cells["txtMachineID"].Value));
                }

                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MachineNo", dtgRow.Cells["txtMachineNo"].Value == DBNull.Value ? "": dtgRow.Cells["txtMachineNo"].Value.ToString());
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Machine", dtgRow.Cells["txtMachine"].Value == DBNull.Value ? "" : dtgRow.Cells["txtMachine"].Value.ToString());
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Active", dtgRow.Cells["blnActive"].Value == DBNull.Value ? "" : dtgRow.Cells["blnActive"].Value.ToString());
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Owned",  dtgRow.Cells["txtOwned"].Value == DBNull.Value ? "" : dtgRow.Cells["txtOwned"].Value.ToString());
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InventoryNo", Convert.ToInt32( dtgRow.Cells["txtInventoryNo"].Value == DBNull.Value ? "0" : dtgRow.Cells["txtInventoryNo"].Value.ToString()));
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notes", dtgRow.Cells["txtNotes"].Value == DBNull.Value ? "" : dtgRow.Cells["txtNotes"].Value.ToString());
                try
                {
                    sqlConn.Open();
                    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,ex.GetType().Name);
                }

                GetDataForGridView();
                sqlConn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Field "MachineNo" has UNIQUE KEY constrain on SQL Server but it is not PRIMARY KEY. Every time when I try to update another field "Machine" I get error:

> Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint. Cannot insert duplicate key in object dbo.pp_Machines.

The duplicate value is value of field MachineNo. But I even do not change the value of this field.

Here is definition of pp_sp_Machine_AddEdit:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


create procedure [dbo].[pp_sp_Machines_AddEdit]
@MachineID int,
@MachineNo varchar(6),
@Machine nvarchar(50),
@Active bit,
@Owned date,
@InventoryNo int,
@Notes ntext

AS 
begin

set nocount on;

if @MachineID=0 
insert into pp_Machines ([MachineNo],[Machine],[Active],[Owned],[InventoryNo],[Notes])
values (@MachineNo,@Machine,@Active,@Owned,@InventoryNo,@Notes)
else
update pp_Machines set 
MachineNo=@MachineNo,
Machine=@Machine,
Active=@Active,
Owned=@Owned,
InventoryNo=@InventoryNo,
Notes=@Notes

end
GO
```

How to solve it?

Maybe there are any replacement to datagridview tool in C#?

Comment: You don't "solve" it, you're not allowed 2 (or more) rows with the same value for `MachineID`. Clearly you appear to either be `UPDATE`ing the value, and it conflicts, or you're `INSERT`ing a new value and it conflicts; we don't know which as we don't have the definition of `pp_sp_Machines_AddEdit`. Also, I suggest not using `AddWithValue`, [it's evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Comment: @Larnu, I have appended my question with pp_sp_Machine_AddEdit definition.

Comment: Your `UPDATE` has no `WHERE`... If your table has more than one row, you're going to `UPDATE` ***every single row***.

Comment: @Larnu, oops, sometime mistakes are so stupid. Thank you for help!
What can be alternative to AddWithValue in C#?

Comment: The article tells you what you should be doing.

Comment: `@Notes ntext` **NO NO NO NO NO!** Deprecated for almost 2 decades. Use nvarchar(max) - and really think about whether you need the "max".